# Setting background image in react using inline CSS based on react logic

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx, css-in-js

I am trying to set the background image of each of the div I get in the return statement based on the string I get from mapping over alcoholistList but can't quite to figure our how to do this.

Below is my code.

Thank you in advance.

```js
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css"

import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import whiskey from '../images/whiskey.jpg'
import gin from '../images/gin.jpg'
import vodka from '../images/vodka.jpg'
import tequila from '../images/tequila.jpg'
import rum from '../images/rum.jpg'

function Home() {

        const alcoholList = useSelector(state => state.alcoholList)

        const history = useHistory()
        const handleClick = (alcoholName) => {
        history.push(`/ingredients?alcohol=${alcoholName}`)
        console.log(alcoholName)
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <div className={styles.homeIngredients}>
                {alcoholList.map(item =>      
                    <div onClick={()=>{handleClick(item)
                        } } className={styles.inner} style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${whiskey})`,
                        }}>
                     
                            <h2>{item}</h2>
                            <p>view recipe</p>
                      
                    </div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you please show what `alcoholList` looks like?

Comment: alcoholList is an array with 5 strings:

["whiskey", "vodka", "gin", "rum", "tequila"]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `alcoholList` looks like, but maybe you can try this :

```
    const ingredients = { whiskey, gin, vodka, tequila, rum };

    return(
        <div>
            <div className={styles.homeIngredients}>
                {alcoholList.map(item =>      
                    <div onClick={()=>{handleClick(item)
                        } } className={styles.inner} style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${ingredients[item]})`,
                        }}>
                     
                            <h2>{item}</h2>
                            <p>view recipe</p>
                      
                    </div>)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work :(

ingredients[item] comes up undefined

Comment: the ```<h2>{item}</h2>``` show you the item ? I don't see why ```ingredients[item]``` would be undefined..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick like this:

First, create an object where the keys are the alcohol names and the values are the images (or image paths). This can be easily done by adding:

```
const ALCOHOL_IMAGES = {whiskey, gin, vodka, tequila, rum}
```

And then, in your map function you can do:

```
{alcoholList.map(item =>      
                    <div onClick={()=>{handleClick(item)
                        } } className={styles.inner} style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${ALCOHOL_IMAGES[item]})`,
                        }}>
//rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

This got fixed!

the reason it didn't work was because the names in alcoholList and the names in the object did not match :|
One was lowercase the other one was capitalized.